# Django Views Join Models Using Foreign Key

Tags: python, django

I have the following models defined:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    Team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Position = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    ... snip ...
```

What I would like to output in a view is a list of players who are in the team with id = 1.

I have tried things such as:

```
{% for player in userTeam.userTeamSquad %}
       <tr><td>{{ player.Name }}</td><td> {{ player.Position }}</td></tr>
{% endfor %}
```

But can't get it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a view that looks something like this:

```
def players(request):
    players_in_team_one = Player.objects.filter(Team__pk = 1)
    return render_to_response('players.html', {'players': players_in_team_one})
```

and you can loop through it like this in `players.html`:

```
{% for player in players %}
       <tr><td>{{ player.Name }}</td><td> {{ player.Position }}</td></tr>
{% endfor %}
```

p.s. As a matter of style, it's more standard to use `all_lowercase_names_with_underscores` as field names.

Comment: Thanks, I will adopt that style also.